# Check if a field is true or false with reflections in java

Tags: java, reflection, boolean, field

Currently trying to code some menu functionality and wondered if there’s a way to find out if a boolean field is true or false. This is the code I’m currently trying but I get an error

```
try{

     field = a.getClass().getField(b); 

     if(toggle==1&&field){
     }else if(toggle==1&&!field){
       field.set(a, true);
     }else if(toggle==0&&!field){
     }else if(toggle==0&&field){
       field.set(a, false);
     }
}catch (NullPointerException e) {
}catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
}catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
}
```

The error is

```
The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, Field
```

Comment: When you know about `set(a, false)`, you should know `get(a)`, or `getBoolean(a)` as well. But why waste time with these redundant checks? `if(toggle==1) field.set(a, true); else if(toggle==0) field.set(a, false);` and that's it. Setting a field to the value it already had has no effect anyway. If `toggle` is always eight zero or one, even `field.set(a, toggle != 0);` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the value of the field based on an instance.

```
boolean value = field.getBoolean(instance);
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.getClass().getField(b);` return `java.lang.reflect.Field;`, not a boolean type.

You could use `field.getBoolean(a)` which get a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

`Class.getField(String)` returns a `java.lang.reflect.Field`. You will want to call `getBoolean` with that `a` as an argument. Note that you are assuming that the field is public, which probably isn't a great idea. Also reflection is usually a really bad idea.